# Doesnt attach file to Gmail

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Programming in kotlin and using an implicit intent. I have created a txt-file and want to attach this automatically to the email created with the intent. This file is not attaching.

```
binding.shareAction.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, File("src/main/java/com/example/openlog/item_logs.txt"))
            sendIntent.type = "*/*"
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. You have a generic Android question.

Answer (score 0):

Need to convert File into Uri.

```
val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                "com.stackkotlin.provider",  //use your app signature + ".provider"
                newFile
            )
```

> Try below code:

```
val newFile = getFileFromAssets(this, "demo.txt")
        val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            "com.stackkotlin.provider",  //use your app signature + ".provider"
            newFile
        )
        Log.e("filePath-----",""+contentUri)
        val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sendIntent.type = "*/*"
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
```

> I am using asset file, Get file from assets folder.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun getFileFromAssets(context: Context, fileName: String): File = File(context.cacheDir, fileName)
        .also {
            if (!it.exists()) {
                it.outputStream().use { cache ->
                    context.assets.open(fileName).use { inputStream ->
                        inputStream.copyTo(cache)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

For getting Uri from File we need file provider

> Add FileProvider in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

> Add `file_paths.xml` file under res-> xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <cache-path
        name="cache"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```